# Weird function declaration (or is it?) in zsh

Tags: function, shell, zsh, zsh-completion

I tried to find certain files by filename creation in zsh (although I read the manpage multiple times I did not *really* now what I was doing), but I think something went terribly wrong:

After I typed echo `10-02-2015.*()`, I was prompted to type something — zsh put out `function>`. I randomly typed in `n`, and pressed enter.

But after that, every command I execute appends “echo:16: command not found: n”, which seems like I defined a function with an empty function name, but I do not see how that makes sense.

With that in mind: What the heck happened here, and how can I revert it?

Comment: I'm going to assume this only affected your current shell and not all shells? Is simply closing that shell session and opening a new one not an option? What does `type -f echo` output? Does `echo "foo"` work correctly?

Comment: ah, it redefined echo to be a function trying to execute `n` —
`type -f echo
echo () {
        n
}`
As expected, `echo "foo"` does not work. `echo` generates two errors btw!

Comment: I'm not sure how that redefined `echo` but yeah that's what it looked like to me (after I poked at zsh for a minute).

Comment: Restarting zsh worked. You can go on and post that as an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick poking at zsh seems to indicate that the first bit of `echo:16: command not found: n` is the command that failed (and the number is the prompt number of the session or something?).

So, somehow, it would seem that whatever you did redefined `echo` as a shell function that is attempting to call `n` (which obviously doesn't exist).

I suspect that `type -f echo` will confirm this and that `echo "foo"` will not work correctly at the moment.

You should be able to simply start a new zsh session to "fix" the problem.

Alternatively, `unset -f echo` appears to work as well.